# Error in executing .EXE file from Qt(release) generated file

Tags: c++, qt

I`m trying to run my .EXE file from my project folder. However when I double click on the file, this error show up:

> The procedure entry point **?toLatin1@QString@@QGBE?AVQByteArray@@XZ** could not be located at dynamic library C:.......\MyProject.exe.

When I run this code on Qt(release) I don't have any issues to solve.

I`m using :
Qt 5.8.0 MSVC 2015 x86/
VS 2015 compiler x86/
OpenCV-2.4.13/
Window 10 w/ Windows kits

Does anyone could help-me?

Comment: Are you trying to deploy the app? If so, have you read Qt's deployment instructions?

Comment: You probably have a different version of Qt binaries somewhere in your PATH environment variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run windeployqt on the executable. To do this, put the executable in its own folder, find out where the windeployqt tool is located (mine is in C:\Qt\5.8\mingw53_32\bin), open a command prompt window, and run the tool with the executable as its argument. For example, if my executable was located at "C:\Users\lrmlrm97\Desktop\Program\program.txt", I would run:

```
cd C:\Qt\5.8\mingw53_32\bin\

windeployqt.exe C:\Users\lrmlrm97\Desktop\Program\program.exe
```